# Access a structure in a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have a pointer which points to the first structure in my linked list, but how can i for example only print out the 5th structure of the linked list?

The linked list consists of 100 structures, all sorted in an order, but how can I print out for example only the 4th and 7th structures of the linked list?

```
struct human {
    char name[STR]; 
    char manuf[STR];
    int age;
    float weight;
    struct human *next; 
}

struct human *current; //Points to current structure.
struct human *first = NULL;

......

 for (current = first; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
     fprintf(stdout, "%s  %s  %d  %f \n", out->name, out->surname,
             out->age, out->weight);
 }
```

"first" will point to the first element of the linked list (it is defined through some function in the code). This code will print out every structure in the linked list, but I only want to print out selected ones, like the 4th and 7th. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Just advance to the next node by however number of times you need to to get to your target node. If you want say, the third node,you have to advance to the next node 2 times. Once to go from node 1 to node 2 and another to go from node 2 to node 3. Your for-loop is doing just that, but it isn't counting how many times it's traversed from one node to the next.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably first learn about linked list traversal through some youtube videos.
You need to start from the head

```
int position= 4;//considering u need to get the 4th element
int output;// stores the final output
struct human *temp= current;
for(i=0; i<position-1;i++)
{
   temp=temp->next;
}
```

at the end of this for loop u will reach the desired node.

```
output= temp->age;//u can access any other data you want as well in the node
```

You also might want to do certain error checks in your for loop like-

```
for(i=0; i<position-1;i++)
{
   temp=temp->next;
   if(temp==NULL)
   {
     break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a skip function such as

```
struct human * skip(struct human * head, int num)
{
    while (num-- > 0)
    {
        head = head -> next;
    }
    return head;
}

struct human * fifth = skip(first, 4);
fprintf(stdout, "%s  %s  %d  %f \n", out->name, out->surname,
         out->age, out->weight);
```

If you'd like to print non-consecutive nodes then you can do something like:

```
int markers[] = { 3, 5, 7};
int index = 0;

for (current = first; current != null ; current = current -> next, index++)
{
    int j;
    for (j=0; j < sizeof(markers)/sizeof(markers[0]); j ++)
    {
       if (markers[j] == index)
       {
             fprintf(stdout, "%s  %s  %d  %f \n", out->name, out->surname,
                              out->age, out->weight);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to define how you are going to get those numbers; Will they be defined in a static way or will be the user who defines it?

Once you got that right, you can store those numbers into an array ordered from min to max and in your loop you can check if the iterator is equal to the next number on your array.

```
int myNumbers[] = {1,2,5};//You will set this values as mentioned in the first place
int iterator = 0, indexToNext=0;
for(current = first; current != NULL; current = current->next, iterator++){
     if (iterator == myNumbers[indextToNext]){
         fprintf(stdout, "%s  %s  %d  %f \n", out->name, out->surname,
                 out->age, out->weight);
         indexToNext++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to have a method that takes an order array of ints that specify the positions you wanted printed like [4,7]. Remember to take in the size of the array. It is important that the array is ordered, or you will have to loop through the linked list a number of times to get all the positions.

Then like you are doing, have a loop that increments a counter and position in the array. If counter == position[x] print. Break the loop when the array is finished or that the linked list is finished.

You may also want to check that the ints with in the array are not greater than the size of the linked list.